# Combined neutral ground bus subpanel

Tags: electrical, subpanel

[image]As I learn more about electrical code, it seems likely I have an incorrect subpanel wiring. One bus contains both neutral and grounds. They should be on separate bars, correct?

Comment: Putting that sub panel in today yes.  Depending on what year the sub panel was put in maybe no.  Nothing is stopping you from adding a ground bus not bonded to the neutral bus.  An expert should be by to say what year the code changed.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the panel in question please?

Comment: 3-wire feeders were banned in 1999 for in-the-building panels, and 2008 for outbuilding panels (they got a little longer because they had local ground rods to help suppress [the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE)).

Answer (score 2):

Correct. Neutral and grounds must be separate in a subpanel.

In a *true* main panel, grounds can be on a neutral bar, but neutrals can never be on a ground bar. Note that there are often (and becoming more common due to code changes):

- Panels that used to be main panels, which are turned into subpanels due to a heavy-up and installation of a new, larger capacity, main panel.
- Panels that used to be main panels, which are turned into subpanels due to installation of a meter-main to provide for large breakers outside (e.g., to feed outbuildings, EV charging, etc.) and/or to provide an outside main disconnect.
- Panels which have always been subpanels (e.g., in a shed or detached garage) which originally had a 3-wire feed (which used to be OK) and are upgraded with a larger 4-wire feed (new larger feed has to meet current code with a ground included) so now have separate neutral and ground coming in but which originally did not have a separate ground wire so neutral and ground were combined.

In all of these cases, the *right* thing to do is to separate neutral and ground. Note that an individual jurisdiction and/or inspector might allow grandfathering of certain exceptions, but modern code requires separate neutral and ground everywhere except in the actual main panel.

To separate neutral and ground:

- Install additional ground bar(s) if needed. Your panel may already have enough ground bars. In particular, check to see how many ground wires are allowed in each ground bar screw - often it is 2 or 3 depending on wire size.
- Move each ground wire to a ground bar.
- While unlikely, it is possible to have some wires that will not reach a ground bar. If so, you will need to add a pigtail (bare or green wire of the same size or larger than the original) to each of those wires. But if that is common then you may be better off adding an additional ground bar in a location that the wires can reach.
- Remove the neutral/ground bond screw or wire.